# Why weren't the Resistance ships crippled by lightning?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, after evil Emperor Palpatine electrocuted the entire Rebel fleet of hundreds of starfighters and cruisers, we came to know that there had been a mass blackout among the ships in the Rebel fleet. We saw the hundreds of fighters and cruisers falling out of the sky, because they had all been crippled. However, when Rey came and Emperor Palpatine paused his destruction, they came back online, pushed themselves back up, and flew right back into battle as if nothing had ever gone wrong.

How is this possible? Wouldn't Palpatine's huge column of lightning, branching off to hit every rebel ship, have crippled at least one? How did every single ship recover without any power loss or damage?

Comment: If I put potatoes in the exhaust pipes of 100 cars, 100% won't start. If I remove those potatoes, 100% of the cars will now start. How did every car recover without damage?

Comment: @Valorum That metaphor's like comparing the electrocuted ships situation to a bunch of straws being clogged by lemon seeds. I wish we were dealing with that, but we're dealing with ships with people in them, with wires that are getting fried, and all shipboard power systems being crippled.

Comment: Because the writing was just that bad

Comment: If no rebel ships were crippled, then that means that the lighting was really weak, the ships were really durable, or, just by chance, 100% of the crucial wires or systems were never burnt out by the electricity.

Comment: It is possible that the ships can withstand a certain amount of damage caused by Force Lightning, without permanent breakdown. Take a RL analogy with military electronics capable of recovering after EMP attacks.

Also, we do not see how many ships were knocked out, some could have been damaged permanently.

Comment: If my dim memories of the _Rogue Squadron_ games are right, ion cannons can temporarily disable a ship without doing any real damage. It's possible that the lightning was doing the same thing, whatever that is.

Comment: It’s not explicitly ever stated, but it’s pretty obvious electricity and repairs seem to work a little... *simpler* in SW

Answer (score -2):

It was because of the intensity of the Force lightning, and that the ships were mostly pretty strong. But, Nien Nunb's ship got crippled by the lightning, probably because it wasn't as strong. Also, wouldn't some of the Sith fleet ships get struck by the lightning attack as well?